# Ignore checkbox that is disable

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, disabled-input

I have here a code that when you clicked the *All* link it will check all the check boxes and when *None* it will uncheck all the check boxes.

But I have a PHP conditions that when the `$pta_fee == $pta_fee_trans` the check box will be disable, but when I clicked the *All* link, the disable check box appears to be checked.

How can I ignore the disable check box if I checked the *All* link?

```
<div class="sub_profile right">
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 25px;'>
    <a href="javascript:selectToggle(true, 'drawing');" id="show">All</a> | <a href="javascript:selectToggle(false, 'drawing');" id="hide">None</a>
     MISCELLANEOUS FEES:
</p>
<?php
    if($pta_fee == $pta_fee_trans)
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $pta_fee; ?>" disabled>
    PTA Fee : &#8369; <?php echo $pta_fee; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='draw[]' value="<?php echo $pta_fee; ?>" id="required-checkbox1" onClick="CheckIfChecked(this.id)">
    PTA Fee : &#8369; <?php echo $pta_fee; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    if($maintenance_fee == $maintenance_fee_trans)
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $maintenance_fee; ?>" disabled>
    Maintenance Fee : &#8369; <?php echo $maintenance_fee; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='draw[]' value="<?php echo $maintenance_fee; ?>" id="required-checkbox2" onClick="CheckIfChecked(this.id)">
    Maintenance Fee : &#8369; <?php echo $maintenance_fee; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    if($id_school == $id_school_trans)
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $id_school; ?>" disabled>
    School ID : &#8369; <?php echo $id_school; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='draw[]' value="<?php echo $id_school; ?>" id="required-checkbox3" onClick="CheckIfChecked(this.id)">
    School ID : &#8369; <?php echo $id_school; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    if($electricity == $electricity_trans)
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $electricity; ?>" disabled>
    Electricity : &#8369; <?php echo $electricity; ?></p>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<p class="sub_content_text" style='margin-left: 30px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='draw[]' value="<?php echo $electricity; ?>" id="required-checkbox4" onClick="CheckIfChecked(this.id)">
    Electricity : &#8369; <?php echo $electricity; ?></p>
<?php
    }
?>
<div id="sub_profile_cont">
    <div class="sub_profile left">
        <p class="block_cont left">
            <div id = "submit-button-container" style="display:none;">
                <input class="action_btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="pay_btn" value="COMPUTE" onClick="setUpdateAction();"/>
            </div>
            <b style="display: none";><input class="action_btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="pay_btn" value="COMPUTE" onClick="setUpdateAction();"/></b>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

--Here's the javascript code for checking all the check boxes:

```
<script>
function selectToggle(toggle, form) {
    var myForm = document.forms[form];
    for( var i=0; i < myForm.length; i++ ) { 
    if(toggle) {
         myForm.elements[i].checked = "checked";
    } 
    else {
         myForm.elements[i].checked = "";
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a hidden field with the boolean value of `$pta_fee == $pta_fee_trans` and then use that hidden field value in your javascript check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function selectToggle(toggle, form) {
    var myForm = document.forms[form];
    for( var i=0; i < myForm.length; i++ ){ 
        if(myForm.elements[i].disabled != true){
            if(toggle){
                 myForm.elements[i].checked = "checked";
            } 
            else{
                 myForm.elements[i].checked = "";
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If it worked, please mark it as the answer.